# JQuery TypeAhead Script not working when script registered from Code Behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, typeahead

I have implemented the JQuery TypeAhead example in this article below and this works fine when the script is added in the aspx page – as in the example

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bootstrap-AutoComplete-TextBox-example-using-jQuery-TypeAhead-plugin-in-ASPNet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx

However, in my working page I am now trying to add the script via code behind (in Page Load) as a proof of concept for a further page where the controls are added dynamically at run time, and only then would the control id’s be known.

I have tried both RegisterClientScriptBlock & RegisterStartupScript but neither seems to work. I have proved that there are no syntax issues in the script as when I paste the generated script into the aspx page and comment out the code behind attempt it works fine. It is somehow down to the script not being registered in time it would seem.

Thanks in advance for any ideas
Lee

RegisterSupplierSearch_AutoCompleteScript is called in Page Load.

Private Sub RegisterSupplierSearch_AutoCompleteScript()
        Dim strContent As New System.Text.StringBuilder

```
    strContent.Append(" <script type=""text/javascript"">")
    strContent.Append("  $(function() { ")
    strContent.Append("  $('[id*=txtSupplierSearch]').typeahead({ ")
    strContent.Append("  hint: true, highlight: true,items: 100,minLength: 3, ")
    strContent.Append("  source: function(request, response) {")
    strContent.Append("  $.ajax({")
    strContent.Append(" url:    '<%=ResolveUrl(""~/Purchasing/POReview2.aspx/GetSuppliers"") %>',")
    strContent.Append("  data: ""{ 'prefix': '"" + request + ""'}"",")
    strContent.Append(" dataType: ""json"",")
    strContent.Append("  type: ""POST"",")
    strContent.Append("  fontSize: ""9px"",")
    strContent.Append("  contentType: ""application/json; charset=utf-8"",")
    strContent.Append(" success: function(data) {")
    strContent.Append("  items = [];")
    strContent.Append("  map = {};")
    strContent.Append("  $.each(data.d, function(i, item) {")
    strContent.Append(" var id = item.split('-')[1];")
    strContent.Append("  var name = item.split('-')[0];")
    strContent.Append("  map[name] = { id: id, name: name };")
    strContent.Append("  items.push(name);")
    strContent.Append("  });")
    strContent.Append("  response(items);")
    strContent.Append(" $("".dropdown-menu"").css(""height"", ""auto"");")
    strContent.Append("   },")
    strContent.Append("  error: function(response) {")
    strContent.Append("  alert('error');")
    strContent.Append(" },")
    strContent.Append("  failure: function(response) {")
    strContent.Append("  alert('failure');")
    strContent.Append("   }")
    strContent.Append("  });")
    strContent.Append("  },")
    strContent.Append("  updater: function(item) {")
    strContent.Append("  $('[id*=txtSupplierSearch]').val(map[item].id);")
    strContent.Append("  var id = item.split(' ')[0];")
    strContent.Append(" return id;")
    strContent.Append(" }")
    strContent.Append("  });")
    strContent.Append(" });")
    strContent.Append(" </script> ")

    Dim csm As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
    Dim ClientScriptName As String = "SupplierSearch"

    'csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, ClientScriptName, strContent.ToString(), False)
    'csm.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, ClientScriptName, strContent.ToString, False)
    'Me.RegisterStartupScript("TypeAhead", strContent.ToString)
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "blah", strContent.ToString(), False)




End Sub
```

Comment: What method are you using to add the JS to the head? I usually leave an asp:Literal inside <head> to fill with scripts in Load() and that works fine. And also, is your jquery wrapped in $(document).ready() ?

Comment: Share with us your code, we don't know what you are doing...

Comment: I've added the code I'm using in the example now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the asp:Literal. Unfortunately this also shows the 'error' alert when added from code behind.